# Converting lvm2 pv to NTFS File system

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, ntfs, nas, lvm2

I have a NAS storage with a 2TB hard drive.

Recently, the NAS storage unit damaged and I want to recover data from the drive. But it was not detectable on my laptop with Windows OS.

When I tried with Manjaro Linux it worked and it shows the file system is lvm2 pv.

When I tried to delete a file from it, it's corrupted, I think. Now I try to mount the drive it shows errors (see screen shots). So, what I am planning to do now is delete the drive partitions and format lvm2 pv to NTFS File system using Gparted, and then recover the data from Windows 10 using easeus data recovery.

Is that possible? Will there be any problems with the files when I am converting to NTFS?

[image: Screenshot 1]

Comment: You have learned - the hard way - the first rule of data recovery: don't change anything until you have recovered everything from it that you possibly can. And that applies now, so make a drive image before you do anything else. I would use `dd` (make sure you include `conv=sync` and be prepared for the corrupts parts to be slow), but there may be Windows alternatives, possibly part of the Easeus package. I wouldn't reformat: you are bound to lose more data, if not all, but you should be able to recover files to a separate partition, NTFS or otherwise.

Comment: @AFH But, dd is not working on drive. not even mounting. I am not changing anything. Just delete the partitions and recover from it after converting to ntfs. I will not write any files in between these process. Is that will work ? Or is there any linux tools that can help ?

Comment: `dd`should work on an unmounted partition.

Comment: @AFH Hi, its a 2TB drive. I don't have a backup disk.

Comment: You can `dd` to standard output, pipe through a compression program, then redirect to a file, which should be around 50% of the original disc size.

Comment: @AFH I haven't tried it yet. Deleting the partition and converting to NTFS and Recovering data from that will work or not .? What't your thoughts ..?

Comment: As you see from my first comment above, I don't recommend it. Rather than try to recover the drive, you should first try to extract whatever files you can to another drive. I have used [PC Inspector](http://www.pcinspector.de/default.htm?language=1) successfully to do this from an SD card, but I have not tried a hard disc. There is also `testdisk` on Linux, which may recover your LVM2 partition, but can't extract files except from FAT/NTFS/extN partitions. If you have copied the disc image and can't recover anything, you can copy back and try again with other recovery software.